# How to display images from my API JSON array?

Tags: json, api, titanium, titanium-alloy

How can I display images from a JSON sub-array which is received via my API?
I can display the title, the price and the description but not the actual image.
Can anyone give me a tip?

My XML:
[image: Screenshot of my xml]

My JSON structure:
[image: Screenshot of my JSON structure]

Comment: Hi, you could not set an array of objects as images. What you need will be something like:
<ImageView image="http://www.url_to_your_image.com">
</ImageView>

Comment: Note that you should write code in the question itself - screenshots of code are *highly* discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to display one image, use a `dataTransform` attribute where you also have the `dataCollection` attribute (see https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding-section-36739592_AlloyDataBinding-Collection-ViewBinding) to select/compose the image URI from the JSON and then use the property in `<ImageView image="{myImage}" />`

Comment: I did that too But it doesn't work <ImageView image="{images[0]}.{sizes[6]}"></ImageView>

Comment: That's not what I suggested. In the XML use `<ImageView image="{myImage}" />` and then where you have the dataCollection attribute, add a dataTransform attribute to pass a function that uses the model to return something like "transformed.myImage = transformed.images[0].sizes[6]". See the link in my previous comment for more guidance.

Comment: link broken @FokkeZandbergen

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the image array and create the ImageView inside JS. To display the images you can use a ScrollableView (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView) and add the images as a view.

Comment: // I did this but it dosen't work                                                                              var args = arguments[0] || {};
var collection = Alloy.Collections.ProductCollection;
collection.fetch({ 
    success : function(){
        _.each(collection.models, function(element, index, list){
          
  element.attributes.images = element.attributes.images[0].sizes['100'];
           
            
        });
    },
    error : function(){
        Ti.API.error("hmm - this is not good!");
    }
});

Comment: I would not recommend going this path. What you want is exactly what dataTransform was made for.